# Can I send money with Paypal API to other paypal account? If yes how?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk, payout

Im doing small business where I often send money with paypal to other paypal accounts. I wonder if I can automate this with Paypal APi. Is there a way to do that? Whats the easiest way for it?

Comment: Adaptive Payment has long time discontinued dude. No more Adaptive Payment in PayPal. Easiest way is to use Website Payment Standard (WPS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adaptive payments will be depreciated soon.

Check Paypal Payouts api. You can send money to 1 or more paypal users.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/

## payouts

[Payout workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woo12.png)